# Install old cocoapods?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

My entire project is wack currently because none of the dependencies are compliant with cocoapods 1.0. Not only are millions of Podspecs not working, there are also multiple other issues which used to be warnings and are now build halting errors... so frustrating.

I have tried removing `~/.cocoapods`, `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` and `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0` and the same errors are occurring. It looks like it's installing it anyway or something?

```
cocoapods (0.39.0)
cocoapods-core (1.0.0, 0.39.0)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.0)
cocoapods-downloader (1.0.0, 0.9.3)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0, 0.4.2)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0, 0.1.0)
cocoapods-stats (1.0.0, 0.6.2)
cocoapods-trunk (1.0.0, 0.6.4)
cocoapods-try (1.0.0, 0.5.1)
```

How do I use 100% old version until these libs are fixed?

Comment: I've been using "pod \_0.39.0\_ install" and "pod \_0.39.0\_ update" to get around some issues I've been having.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Step 1** Run `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0`, this will install the version you want.

**Step 2** Run `sudo gem list`, which will give you a list of all the gems you have installed as well as their version; you'll note that you have multiple versions of cocoapods installed.

**Step 3** Uninstall the version(s) you don't want with `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -v 1.0`.

**Step 4** Confirm you are now running the correct version of cocoapods with `pod --version`.

Comment: Oops that was a typo, sorry... but when I do that I still get the same errors:

Comment: [!] Found multiple specifications for `AppLovin (3.2.2)`

Comment: @Tallboy If you run `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0` and then run `sudo gem list` you should be able to see you've got multiple versions of cocapods installed. Uninstall the version you don't want with `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.0`. I tested this myself. You can check your cocapods version with before and after with `pod --version`. Hopefully that helps.